# How to set path name for listing all the '.xml' files using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery to list all the xml files in a folder. These files will be listed in Drop-down box...Below is my coding which is not reading all the files, instead reads the content of  the first picked file...

Script:

```
var dir = '/DenaRest/';
            var fileextension=".xml";
              $.ajax({
                 url: dir,
                    success: function (data) {
                  alert(data);
                        //Lsit all png file names in the page
                        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
                            var fileName = $(this).attr("href");
                            alert("Found a file: " + fileName);


                        });
                    }
                });
```

Dena Rest is my web application name..I have 3 xml files inside this...
Please help on this...

Comment: Why don't you AJAX a PHP file that reads the files in a directory for you and sends that back?

Comment: Dont we have any other way of doing it...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding the difference between client and server side processing. jQuery is running on the client (i.e. in the user's browser). This cannot see your server, it can simply talk to id (traditionally via HTTP). THis means you cannot traverse the filesystem of the server with jQuery. Instead you will need to use a server technology. Examples:

1. PHP
2. ASP
3. ASP.NET
4. Node.js

Comment: Thanks for explaining...somewhere I missed this point(infact the core)...Shall I read the file names through Servlet and can i pass those values to JQuery??

Comment: Absolutely. Maybe provide a method that you can call from jQuery to retrieve the paths. Or rather if there are only few, make a single server method to return all the information you need in a single request.

Comment: Also i read somewhere that, if the folder is made browsable, then it will be possible to accessed through JQuery...

Comment: That's not an ideal approach. Every time you look for a file, you're making a request to the server. This is very time consuming and eats up a lot of bandwidth. You're best off asking the server to give you everything you need, then process on the client for presentation purposes.